# Parse error when building my matrix, do not understand why

Tags: matrix, octave, parse-error

I'm trying to build a matrix out of linear equations but for some reason I keep getting a parse error in my matrix when previously I did not.

```
CoM=[K1*(abs(Q1).^r) K2*(abs(Q2).^r) -(K3*(abs(Q3).^r)) -(K4*(abs(Q4).^r)); K3*(abs(Q3).^r) -(K5*(abs(Q5).^r)) -(K6*(abs(Q6).^r) -(K7*(abs(Q7).^r) ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 1 -1 0 ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 1 -1 0];
                                                                                                                                                        ^
error: parse error near line 1 of file '____'\WNA2loop.m
 syntax error
    CoM=[K1*(abs(Q1).^r) K2*(abs(Q2).^r) -(K3*(abs(Q3).^r)) -(K4*(abs(Q4).^r)); K3*(abs(Q3).^r) -(K5*(abs(Q5).^r)) -(K6*(abs(Q6).^r) -(K7*(abs(Q7).^r) ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 1 -1 0 ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 1 -1 0];
                                                                                                                                                            ^
```

Right where I put the caret but when I take that small part of the matrix and run the command it

```
[1 -1 0 0 ; 1 1 -1 0 ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 -1 0 0 ; 1 1 -1 0]
ans = 1  -1   0   0
      1   1  -1   0
      1  -1   0   0
      1  -1   0   0
      1   1  -1   0
```

The K1 to K7 and Q1 to Q7 as well as the are just variables that get input by the user through the input function it worked before but now it just wont budge, could someone please provide assistance on this?

Comment: You're missing close parentheses around the K6/K7 sections. And those variables K1 to K7 and Q1 to Q7 are serious code smell. Those should probably be arrays of some sort.